# Laravel Multiple Route in SameController

Tags: php, laravel

```
Route::get('/blog', 'BlogController@index')->name('blog');
Route::get('/blog/tag/{tag}', 'BlogController@index')->name('blog');
Route::get('/blog/category/{category}', 'BlogController@index')->name('blog');
```

I want to redirect different urls to same controller.

If the user filter for tag, send me link like : blog/tag/sample-tag

Or category : blog/category/sample-category

Or if user wants to see all blog : blog

I want to check in BlogController's index method like :

```
if ($request->has('tag') // return tag's blog content
else if ($request->has('category') // return category's blog content
else // return all blog content.
```

**Laravel 5.6.***

Error:

> Missing required parameters for [Route: blog] [URI:
>   blog/category/{category}]

I call like this : `<li><a href="{{ route('blog') }}">BLOG</a></li>`

Comment: While you could use the same controller, I wouldn't recommend using the same route name or the same controller method.  Why do the second two need to use the index method?

Comment: sorry my bad, i update with the error

Comment: should i create another controller for tag and category? @Devon

Comment: If you want to filter a resource index its better to use the query string, i.e: `/blog?tag=laravel&category=programming`

Comment: @dparoli is it good for seo?

Comment: Dunno for seo, but, IMHO its the best way to handle filtered restful resources. Your routes, as written, are prone to a lot of interpretation errors by the Laravel routing system:  same name for different routes, parameters confusions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better to sperate your routes into different controller method

```
// Define routes
Route::get('/blog', 'BlogController@index')->name('blog');
Route::get('/blog/tag/{tag}', 'BlogController@tag')->name('blog.tag');
Route::get('/blog/category/{category}', 'BlogController@category')->name('blog.category');

// Generate url
route('blog');
route('blog.tag', ['tag' => $tag]);
route('blog.category', ['category' => $category]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use
`Route::get('/blog/{second?}/{third?}','BlogController@index')->where(['second'=>'tag|category']);`

Answer (score 0):

It is better to separate your routes but you can do this by injecting the model into your method like this code:

```
public function index (?Tag $tag, ?Category $category)
{
    if($tag->exists){
       ....
    }
    if($category->exists){
       ....
    }
}
```